# The CellClick DataGridView in the combobox does not appear in the vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, datagridview, combobox

The CellClick DataGridView in the combobox does not appear in the vb.net.

is there something wrong in my code?
I updated the code from me so that the answer can be adjusted in the code because I am still confused with the answer

thanks

```
'load database to datatable then to datagridview
 Private Sub LoadData(Optional ByVal keyword As String = "")

        Sql = "SELECT Auto_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, [First_Name] + ' ' + [Last_Name] AS Full_Name, Gender FROM TBL_SMART_CRUD " &
              "WHERE [First_Name] + ' ' + [Last_Name] LIKE @keyword1 OR Gender = @keyword2 ORDER BY Auto_ID ASC"

        Dim dt As DataTable = PerformCRUD(Cmd)
'update binding source
        BindingSource1.DataSource = dt
        With DataGridView1
            .MultiSelect = False
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
'update binding source
            .DataSource = BindingSource1
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "First Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Last Name"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Full Name"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Gender"
        End With
    End Sub
'module AccessDb_Connection.vb
Public Function PerformCRUD(ByVal Com As OleDbCommand) As DataTable
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter
            da.SelectCommand = Com
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " & ex.Message, "Perform CRUD OPERATIONS Failed. : Tutorial",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            dt = Nothing
        End Try
        Return dt
        End
    End Function
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

        Dim dgv As DataGridView = DataGridView1

        If e.RowIndex <> -1 Then

            IDTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value).Trim()
            UpdateButton.Text = "UPDATE (" & Me.ID & ")"
            DeleteButton.Text = "DELETE (" & Me.ID & ")"
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value).Trim()
            LastNameTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value).Trim()

            GenderComboBox.SelectedItem = Convert.ToString(dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value).Trim()

        End If

    End Sub
```

[String collection editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMW8S.jpg)
[cellclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bolLA.jpg)

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve. I suspect that handling the `CellClick` event would not be the best solution, even if it did work as you expect.

Comment: @John , you can see the screeshot that I attached and in the textbox it appears but only in the combobox it does not appear

Comment: @John , I've removed the best solution, so here I just want to show up in the combobox

Comment: I repeat, please explain what you're actually trying to achieve. Neither of your comments goes any way to doing that. I'm asking you to describe, in detail, exactly what functionality this code is supposed to be implementing. For one thing, it's possible to perform many actions using the keyboard or the mouse, which is why reacting to clicks specifically is often not the right thing to do. Please update the question with a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem which ALWAYS includes an explanation of what you're trying to achieve and not just how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're trying to do. You have data in a `DataGridView` and, when a user selects a row, you want the cell values from that to be editable in a number of discrete controls, including `TextBoxes` and a `ComboBox`. Is that correct? If so then you should be using data-binding, in which case you don't need any code at all. If you can confirm that this is what you want, I will post an answer to that effect.

Comment: Also, where did the data in the grid come from in the first place and how did it get into the grid? is it from a database? Did you populate a `DataTable`? Did you bind that `DataTable` to the grid?

Comment: @John , `you want the cell values from that to be editable in a number of discrete controls, including TextBoxes and a ComboBox. Is that correct?` yes right because i want to use it to do CRUD,

Comment: @John , it comes from the access database via oledb and yes I population the datatable and then to the datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are retrieving data from a database into a `DataTable` and binding that to the `DataGridView`. In that case, you should bind that same `DataTable` to the individual controls. That way, selecting a row in the grid will automatically load that same row into the individual controls. You should also add a `BindingSource` to your form and bind through that, if you aren't already. E.g.

```vb
thingBindingSource.DataSource = thingDataTable
thingDataGridView.DataSource = thingBindingSource
stuffTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", thingBindingSource, "Stuff")
```

When you add a binding to a control, the first argument is the name of the control property and the last is the name of the source column/property. In the case of a `ComboBox`, you would normally bind data from another table and display a name/description and hide the ID, then have the ID populate a foreign key column in the other table. That might look like this:

```vb
With otherStuffComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "Name"
    .ValueMember = "ID"
    .DataSource = referenceListDataTable
    .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", thingBindingSource, "ForeignKeyColumn")
End With
```

It sounds like you're not doing that though. It sounds like you just have a list of `Strings` in the `ComboBox` and they are populating the other table directly. In that case, you can bind to the `SelectedItem` rather than the `SelectedValue`.

By the way, if you want to save changes to the database, you should be saving all the changes from the `DataTable` using the same data adapter that you used to populate it in the first place. Each time you edit a row, those changes are stored in the `DataTable`. You can navigate around and edit as many rows as you like and all changes are stored. To delete, you call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource` and that change is stored too. You can then call `Update` on a data adapter to save all the changes in a batch.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am still confused about using so i updated the code from my post so please you can customize from my code

Comment: @user19530941, what's the confusing part? You've got a `DataTable` and you're binding it to the grid. I told you to bind it to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid. I also told you to bind it to your other controls. I showed you how to do both. What exactly is confusing you about this?

Comment: I've updated the code in my post with bindingsource is that correct

Comment: @user19530941, please don't modify your question so that it's no longer asking the same thing. If you need to correct a mistake then do so but, otherwise, you should be adding information rather than editing it.

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong and I created like this binding code in the textbox  . `IDTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "Auto_ID")`

Comment: @user19530941, did it work? Were you able to select a row in the grid and see that `TextBox` populated automatically? Were you able to edit the data in the `TextBox` and see the grid updated? Note that the grid will not update immediately. If you don't explicitly commit the change, you'd have to at least shift focus to another control and you may have navigate to a different record. That's why you need to commit before saving, which you do by calling `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource`.

Comment: the result works and what if I want to update from the textbox by using the "button" event

Comment: @user19530941, there is no "update from the textbox". The changes are stored in the bound `DataTable`. As I already said, you call `update` on your data adapter to save those changes.